# How to remove UIImageView's last image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `UIImageView` that changes pictures depending on a level. But every time I change it, the last image is retained and the Memory usage keeps going up. I think the imageView is stacking the images on top of another. I've tried setting `self.imageView.image = nil` before setting the new image, but that doesn't seem to work. How do I correctly do this?

```
if (level == 1) {
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1"];

} else if (level == 2) {
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2"];

} else if (level == 3) {
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3"];
```

Comment: No it is not, dont worry about your memory usage, it will get freed at some point.

Comment: It usnt retained, it is cached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to
>   ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should
>   instead create your image using imageWithContentsOfFile:. This will
>   keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially
>   improving the memory use characteristics of your app.

Read here: [UIImage Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:)

Conclusion, using imageNamed adding image to cache and might eventually increase memory use. Instead, use imageWithContentsOfFile so image won't be adde to cache.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers already say that the image is cached by the system and therefore its memory is not freed. But that is nothing for you to worry about at the time.

If the system feels like it needs more memory it is going to clear caches, effectively clearing the memory of the image and reusing it for something else.

Dont worry about the memory usage unless you see serious problems. And if that is the case, `imageNamed` is probably the least of your worries.

**General note to consider**:

Wether or not to make use of the caching depends entirely on your use case. If you show the same image quite often and load it in a few different places, make use of the caching. If you show an image just once, use `imageWithContentsOfFile`.

Comment: Theoretically I agree, however, if one use imageNamed thousands of times, system might end up behaving way worse than using imageWithContentsOfFile. So if a developer wants to be accurate, he she should follow this practice.

Comment: @RoyK It depends entirely on your use case, caching is there for a reason, if you are going to reuse the image often, make us of it, if you show every image exactly once during the entire runtime, use `contentsOfFile`

Comment: Indeed, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @RoyK perfect! :) I already upvoted your question (was a lot better than the first one)

Comment: @RoyK I will include it in the post.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are running into is caused by the invocation of UIImage imageNamed is caching the decoded image data in memory. Load the image with imageWithContentsOfFile instead and only the active image will be held in memory.